# Reciving Text in Telegram BOT use PHP

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I use this code in my script to receive text from user but it doesn't save anything. What am I doing wrong.The user has to determine and send the rules for his group here
thank

```
<?
//------------------Group SetRules---------------
if($data == "group_setrules" ) 
if($admin == $from_id2 || $owner2 == $from_id2 || strpos($modlist2 , "$from_id2") !== false){
  
var_dump(makereq('editMessageText',[
          'chat_id'=>$chat_id2,
          'parse_mode'=>'HTML',
          'message_id'=>$message_id2,
"text" => '<b>Group Rules</b>',
'reply_markup' =>json_encode([
'inline_keyboard'=>[

[
['text'=>'❌ back','callback_data'=>'group_rules'],
]
],
          ])
          ]));
}
//---------------SetRules Input--------------
if (strpos($textmessage , " " ) !== false ){
  $text = str_replace("","",$textmessage);
file_put_contents("data/$chat_id/rules.txt","$text");  
    var_dump(makereq('sendMessage',[
          'chat_id'=>$chat_id2,
          'parse_mode'=>'HTML',
          'message_id'=>$message_id2,
          
'text'=>"Rules are Set",

'reply_markup' =>json_encode([
'inline_keyboard'=>[
[
['text'=>'back','callback_data'=>'group_rules'],
]
]
          ])
      ]));
}
?>
```

Comment: Does the `var_dump` portion fire at least? Also, your very first `if` statement doesn't have braces `{}`, is that intentional? It could drastically change your code otherwise.

Comment: 1. No / 2.Yes . I change the code, maybe it works. Thanks